# How can I Add Extra Theme To Sharepoint Performance Point Service

Tags: sharepoint, themes, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint

I use `Share point 2013` .
I want add a extra theme to my `share point` site.

I use this way for change theme `Site Settings -> Change the look`

How can I download extra theme from internet and load to my `Share point` website ?

Answer (score 1):

You can build your own themes using the Color Palette tool --> http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=38182. There are also themes that you can buy --> http://bindtuning.com/cms/sharepoint/sharepoint-2013/. I haven't seen any free themes that aren't just created using the above mentioned color palette tool.